# HTML opposite of non-breaking space

Tags: html, css

In my HTML I have a very long word and I'm trying to force a specific break point only when there isn't enough room. What I need is a sort of conditional-breaking placeholder. How can I achieve this sort of thing?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Maybe the Unicode zero-width space would help: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b/index.htm

The HTML entity is `&#8203;` e.g.
`over&#8203;flow` will break the word between "over" and "flow" only when the full word doesn't fit.

Comment: perfect! I didn't even know there was such a thing.

Comment: To save you all the link, the HTML entity is &#8203;

Answer (score 23):

The tag `<wbr>` (for Word BReak) will do what you want.

Comment: You posted two different answers? Shouldn't you combine them into one? I'm pretty sure they both work.

Comment: @JuanMendes: I think the preference on SO is to keep separate answers separate.

Comment: @NedBatchelder I see... http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25209/what-is-the-official-etiquette-on-answering-a-question-twice

Comment: There's also `&shy;` for the soft hyphen

Answer (score 1):

I'll post another alternative, as that's what I actually was looking for the first time I found this question.

You should use a [Soft hyphen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_hyphen) instead of [Zero-width space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space).

From [Soft hyphen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_hyphen):

> **soft hyphen** or **syllable hyphen**, abbreviated **SHY**, is a code point reserved in some coded character sets for the purpose of
>   breaking words across lines by inserting visible hyphens.

Also, to compare it with "Zero-width space", from [Soft hyphen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_hyphen):

> It serves as an **invisible marker used to specify a place in text where
>   a hyphenated break is allowed without forcing a line break in an
>   inconvenient place** if the text is re-flowed. It becomes visible only
>   after word wrapping at the end of a line. The soft hyphen's Unicode
>   semantics and HTML implementation **are in many ways similar to
>   Unicode's zero-width space, with the exception that the soft hyphen
>   will preserve the kerning of the characters on either side when not
>   visible**. The zero-width space, on the other hand, will not, as it is
>   considered a visible character even if not rendered, thus having its
>   own kerning metrics.

You can also check out the wikipedia article with an example text that changes when the window resizes.

Answer (score 0):

the opposite of br :

```
<nobr>   </nobr>
```

regards

Answer (score -1):

The Microsoft CSS rule "word-wrap:word-break" should do what you want and is supported by most older browsers

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/word-wrap

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms531186(v=vs.85).aspx

There is also now a WC3 version - "overflow-wrap:break-word;" and as you can read in the spec "For legacy reasons, UAs must treat ‘word-wrap’ as an alternate name for the ‘overflow-wrap’ property, as if it were a shorthand of ‘overflow-wrap’." - so you may want to test wether your browser set is actually implementing this.

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/#overflow-wrap

http://caniuse.com/#search=overflow-wrap

You could always play it safe and use both

```
p.breaklongwords {
    word-wrap:word-break;
    overflow-wrap:break-word;
}
```

Comment: I originally tried the `word-wrap:word-break` but it didn't work well enough for me. I'll try also using `overflow-wrap`.

Comment: @Andrew Is that because you want to dictate the exact point where a break may occur?

Comment: That is what prompted this question, but that wasn't the reason it didn't work originally. I was having issues in a mobile responsive layout where the long word would force the width of the layout off the screen, and setting word-wrap did cause the word to wrap, but the width was still being forced too wide. Adding a physical space fixed the problem, but I would prefer to use the "zero width space" character instead.

Comment: Did you try also applying overflow:hidden to the content's box so it didn't also overflow -- makes me hit pause whenever I think hardcoding stuff like this into content is the only way out...

Comment: Yep, I tried that too. Spent half a day pulling my hair out over this =/